# the dimension of the space of solution of the system of linear equation given by $AX=0$

Tags: linear-algebra

$A$ be a $m\times n$ matrix with row and column rank $r$, I need to know the dimension of the space of solution of the system of linear equation given by $AX=0$ by the approach of linear transformation.

I see this is a map from $\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^m $ given by $X\mapsto AX$, and hence I need to find the dimension kernel of this map.

am I right upto here?

Now how do I apply here $\dim \operatorname{Ker} T+\dim\operatorname{Im} T=\dim V$

Thank you.

Comment: I've cleaned up the question a bit, making some changes in the second paragraph as well (the map defined by a $m\times n$ matrix $A$ starts in dimension$~n$ rather than$~r$, and the argument of this map is of course not $A$ itself); I hope you see this as an improvement. For the question itself, what do you know about the rank? (And which of the spaces involved is$~V$?)

Comment: Well, you **need** to know/find out either $\,\dim\ker T\;$ or $\;\dim\text{Im}\,T\;$ ...

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Thank you very much for the edit, well $V=\mathbb{R}^n$ so could you please now tell me what is the dimension of image T?

Comment: $\dim\text{Im}\,T=\dim V-\dim\ker T\;$ and nothing else more general can be said in a general case.

Comment: @nonlinear: If you tell me what the rank of $A$ is defined to be, then I will tell you what the dimension of the image of $T$ is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have
$$\{\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^n|A\mathbf{x}=0\}=:\ker A$$
so the dimension you're looking for is $\dim\ker A$. As you have stated, we have the formula
$$\dim \mathbb{R}^m = \dim\ker A+\dim A\mathbb{R}^n$$
Now notice that $\dim A\mathbb{R}^n=\operatorname{rank} A$, thus
$$\dim\ker A = m - r$$